# How To Pass a MultiDimensional Array from Javascript to server using PageMethods in ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webmethod, pagemethods

I have some `<li>` Items in my HTML Page like this

```
<li id="A1" class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li id="A2" class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li id="A3" class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li id="A4" class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
```

I called It using Javascript and Jquery like this to get the Id and Index of the `<li>` elements

```
function LiOrder() {
            var order = $('li').map(function (i) {
                return { id: this.id, index: i };
            }).get();

            PageMethods.GetServerResponse(order, OnSuccess, OnFail);
        }

        function OnSuccess(arg) {
            alert(arg);
        }
```

WebMethod Written in Aspx.cs Page is this

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string GetServerResponse(string[,] LiOrder)
    {


        return LiOrder[0,0];
    }
```

But when I try to execute it I get Error like this in Google Chrome (Javascript Console)

```
POST http://localhost:2453/ERP29.1.13/Production/LifeCycleRegistration.aspx/GetServerResponse 500 (Internal Server Error) ScriptResource.axd:6979
```

What might be the reason for this error. I could pass a string to WebMethod like this. But when it comes to Array, its like this. Please Help me to resolve this

Comment: use string only. it's not multi dimension array.

Comment: Can't we pass Array to PageMethods

Comment: While debugging It showed me as an Array.

Comment: whatever you send it will be string or object in javascript. you can json.stringfy, and send the string to method

Comment: Tried with string too. Nothing changes

Comment: How to stringfy it in Javascript.

Comment: Please make it as an answer. Its working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON.stringfy resolved my issue. I changed my code like this

```
var LiArr=JSON.stringify(order);
            PageMethods.GetServerResponse(LiArr, OnSuccess, OnFail);
```

Comment: Hi. I've faced with the same problem. But your solution doesn't work for me. My jquery and c# method exactly the same with yours. But JSON.stringify makes my array a string. I need multidimensional array of data. Do you know why it is happening?