# Can't pass multidimensional array to server side with PageMethods -Jquery/C#

Tags: c#, jquery, arrays, type-conversion, pagemethods

My problem is exactly this : [How To Pass a MultiDimensional Array from Javascript to server using PageMethods in ASP.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15291347/how-to-pass-a-multidimensional-array-from-javascript-to-server-using-pagemethods)

I am trying to do same thing but the solution doesn't work for me and i'm confused. He says `JSON.stringify` works but it makes my object array a entire `string`. I can't use `string[,]` or `List<string>` for parameter type. If i don't use `JSON.stringify` i can pass data with `List<object>` type. But i couldn't get values in c#. So i need some help. **Basically;** i need to pass my multidimensional array to c# and i must get values with in loop. So need some advice. Here's my code:

Jquery:

```
var fixedQuestions = $(".questId").map(function () {
    return { group:$(this).closest('li').attr('id') , id:$(this).text() };
}).get();
var test1 = JSON.stringify(fixedQuestions);
PageMethods.InsertAuditParams(test1);
```

and here is my c# Web Method:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void InsertAuditParams(string[,] testarray)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < testarray.Length; i++)
    {
        string value1 = testarray[i, 0].ToString();
    }
}
```

and this is the error that i get on firebug console:

...Cannot convert object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.String[,]'

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it. It was about passed collection type. It was look like `dictionary` type at c# and that's why i couldn't get values. So i created a js function for manupulate the data as i want. Here is the solution for new comers;

```
function ConvertToArray(objectData)
    {
        var multiArray = [];
        for (var key in objectData) { multiArray.push([objectData[key].num,                
        objectData[key].text]); }
        return multiArray;
    }
var passFixed = ConvertToArray(fixedQuestions);

PageMethods.InsertAuditParams(passFixed);
```

and this is how to get values at c#:

```
public static void InsertAuditParams(List<object> fixed_q)
{
    foreach (object[] item in fixed_q)
        {
            string value1 = item[0].ToString();
            string value2 = item[1].ToString();
        }
}
```